# RealURL error: wrong "L" parameter value

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

RealURL gives this error.

My site has only one language, and I have not added any website language in root page.

I tried with `config.linkVars = L` and `config.linkVars = L(0-5)` in the setup with no effect.

[image]

RealURL Config is auto-generated:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/'
        ),
        'pagePath' => array(
            'rootpage_id' => '1'
        ),
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
            'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
            'index' => array(
                'print' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 98
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'news' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thats a RealURL 2.1.7 problem.
I downgrade to RealURL 2.1.5 and then it works.

EDIT:
Now i add `page.theme.language.languageValue = 0` to my template constants

Answer (score 0):

See => https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/407

A quick fix for 2.1.7 can be a strict assignment of the configured "uid" integer values

```
linkVars = L(0-1)
```

… did the job for me. Instead of L(0-3)